# Numbers of characters in a PHP variable?

Tags: php

OK there is an input field for visitor to enter something in it (like nickname lets say). I wish for (upcoming $_POST) variable to have at least (at least) 4 characters before starts to trigger function.

Here is some cosmetic example..

```
$inputdata = escapeHTML($_REQUEST['data']);

if($inputdata...)
{
//execute $inputdata
}
```

Any cool trick? Thx!

Comment: Trick? Why not just `strlen`?

Comment: Or `mb_strlen` if the input is possibly non-latin text.

Comment: Googling your exact title lands you on the manual page for strlen.

Comment: @putvande Yeah I was to lazy to google for it so wanted to send someone 15pts ;)

Comment: PS: Why are you voting for closing this question and giving minuses for? Its a normal question, very clearly asked, and newbie programmers will find it very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (strlen($inputdata) >= 4)
```

This should work then

Or

```
 if (mb_strlen($inputdata) >= 4) for non-latin text
```

Resources:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: Thx 1ntello! :) Please await answer accept in a minute or so ;)